# script full name and path $0 not visible when called

Tags: bash, shell, argv

I have a script "task.sh" with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

CUR_DIR=`pwd`
SCRIPTPATH="${CUR_DIR}/`dirname $0`"
```

when I call it with "bash task.sh" it works as expected but when it is called with ". task.sh"

```
$ . log/task.sh 
dirname: invalid option -- b
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
```

When the script is being scheduled in crontab it is not working as well.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong or a different way in order to get the directory of a script that is not the current directory
?

Comment: Just quick guess: try `SCRIPTPATH="${CUR_DIR}/\`dirname "$0"\`"`, i.e. quote `$0`. Besides that, `CUR_DIR` seems to be redundant here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you invoke it as `bash task.sh`, bash assigns "task.sh" to $0 (from the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters): "If Bash is invoked with a file of commands [...] $0 is set to the name of that file.").

When you source the file, bash does not alter $0, it just executes the script in the current environment. What's in $0 in your current enviroment?

```
$ echo "$0"
-bash
```

The leading dash will be interpreted by `dirname` as an option.

If it's in a cron job, why are you sourcing it?

If you need to source your script, this will work if your shell is bash:

```
SCRIPTPATH="${CUR_DIR}/${BASH_ARGV[0]}"
```

However, cron's shell is, I believe, /bin/sh.  Even if /bin/sh is a symlink to bash, when bash is invoked as sh it will try to behave POSIXly: the BASH_ARGV array probably won't be available to you.

Comment: Wrote it like this and now working perfect :) 
`CUR_DIR="$PWD"
SCRIPTFILE=$0
if [ "${SCRIPTFILE}" = "-bash" ] ; then
 SCRIPTFILE=${BASH_ARGV[0]}
fi
SCRIPTPATH="${CUR_DIR}/`dirname ${SCRIPTFILE}`"`

Answer (score 2):

I have used this for a long time without issues.

```
SCRIPTPATH=$(cd `dirname -- $0` && pwd)
```

The `--` disable further processing of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to call external binaries such as `pwd` and `dirname` when using bash.  The functionality of these two binaries can be replicated with pure shell syntax.

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

CUR_DIR="$PWD"
SCRIPTPATH="${CUR_DIR}/${0#*/}"
```

Comment: This requires you to be in the same directory as the script when you run it... not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

When you type,

```
bash foo.sh
```

you are executing script foo.sh, and bash sets the input argument $0 to the name of the script which is being run.

When you type,

```
. foo.sh
```

you are sourcing the script and the input argument $0 is not set. 
In this situation you can use the automatic variable $_ which contains the argument of the last executed command.
In your script you could type,

```
SCRIPTPATH=$(dirname "$_")
```

to get the path of foo.sh.
Notice that, for this to work, this has to be the first command executed in the file.
Otherwise $_ will not contain the path of the sourced script.

Kudos to [Dennis Williamson](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/382/dennis-williamson) for providing this answer to a similar [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4650/determining-path-to-sourced-shell-script).