# Tomcat 8.0 wont run on mac

Tags: macos, tomcat, tomcat8

I have a fresh installation of tomcat 8.0
When i run the startup.sh script i get:

```
    dirname: illegal option -- b
usage: dirname path
catalina.sh
Cannot find /catalina.sh
The file is absent or does not have execute permission
This file is needed to run this program
```

So i echo the `EXECUTABLE` variable located in the `startup.sh` script and i get the filename correctly 'see the `catalina.sh` log above, which is not part of the standard log'.
since the file exists, i believe the only problems are permissions, and indeed i see that i do not have exec `x` rights:

```
    ls -l startup.sh
-rw-r--r--@ 1 USERNAME  admin  1931 Apr 26 14:32 startup.sh
```

So i modify them:

```
    chmod a+x *
    ls -l startup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 USENAME  admin  1931 Apr 26 14:32 startup.sh
```

Now that i have the permissions, i execute the file.
But i get the same error again.
The strange thing is that if i run tomcat from within a server instance in Eclipse, it works fine.
But as far as i know Eclipse run the exact same `startup.sh` script.
any tips? thx

Comment: Depending on how you have Eclipse setup you could be running the embedded server in the war file (That is only assuming you are using Java). How did you install it? I used `brew` once and had a few issues. I like to download it from `apache` and manually place it in the `/opt/` directory. Then configure the `users and conf xml` file.

Comment: related ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708339/script-full-name-and-path-0-not-visible-when-called  (try to execute `bash startup.sh` to see if it makes any diference)

Comment: The same is the case on my tomcat 6. @JBoy: Anything you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All shell files in bin should have execution excess. Try doing this:

`chmod +x bin/catalina.sh`

you might get this message

```
The BASEDIR environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
```

try doing 
chmod +x *.sh 
or
chmod +x bin/*.sh

It worked for me